# Override or unset a variable set with SetEnvIfNoCase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, setenv

I use the following code in my httpd.conf to block some unwanted old browsers

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (msie\s7) blocked=old

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=blocked
```

The following useragent however should not be blocked (Microsoft Office uses this useragent):

```
mozilla/4.0 (compatible; msie 7.0; windows nt 6.1; win64; x64; trident/7.0; .net clr 2.0.50727; slcc2; .net clr 3.5.30729; .net clr 3.0.30729; media center pc 6.0; .net4.0c; .net4.0e; ms-office; msoffice 16)
```

**Question:**
How do I override or unset a variable set with SetEnvIfNoCase?

Will this work?

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (msoffice) blocked=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exclamation mark will remove a variable if already defined:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (msoffice) !blocked
```

Source:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html